# requirejs - loading the same module with a different name in different files

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Using requirejs, I have two files that depend on the same module.
Must I make sure that I always use the same module name in both dependencies?
For example, if I defined a path for require.config:

```
'myMod':'src/js/myModule'
```

And then one time use the name and one time use the actual path, like so:

```
//in a.js
define(function(require){
 var mod = require('myMod');
});

//in b.js
define(function(require){
 var mod = require('src/js/myModule');
});
```

Obviously, the best practice would be to use the module name everywhere, but I want to know why this causes an actual error.

Does requirejs store a map between the module name used and the actual loaded module?

Answer (score 4):

As you yourself say:

> Obviously, the best practice would be to use the module name everywhere

RequireJS enforces this practice, up to a point. The thing is that when you tell RequireJS in your `paths` that `'myMod':'src/js/myModule'` you are effectively saying that you want to load `src/js/myModule` under the name `myMod`. In all likelihood, if you then refer to it by the full path this is an error in your part. If this were to happen in my code, I'd consider it to be an error. So I'd like RequireJS to fail when this happens.

There's also the issue of semantics. The basic case is that if two names passed to `require` differ, once relative paths have been resolved, then they refer to two different modules. Going by this, if you do `require('myMod')` and `require('src/js/myModule')` you are expecting two *different* modules. And if you do `require('myMod')` and `require('myMod')`, you get the *same* module. So with the `paths` you've set, what do you actually want? The *same* module or *different* modules?

RequireJS has ways to give you both. If you want both module names to give you the same module, then you remove your `paths` config and use a `map` config instead:

```
map: {
  '*': {
    myMod: 'src/js/myModule'
  }
}
```

What this means is "in all modules (`*`), if a request is made for the module `myMod`, then load module `src/js/myModule` instead." The intent is crystal clear.

If you'd like instead both paths to give you different modules *although they share the same source*, you could do it using a RequireJS plugin that loads the same source for your modules but has RequireJS register this single source as different modules.